# Javascript: Convert object to array with sort

Tags: javascript

I need to convert object to several arrays, without duplicate keys, if there is a key that consist "user_" or "city_", create new array.
The first three props/keys always are the same.

for example

```
const test = {
    "mainPoint": "user1",
    "create_Date": "2018-04-23 16:51:10",
    "delete_Date": "2018-04-23 16:50",
    "user_one": 4,
    "user_two": 4,
    "city_one": bs,
    "city_two": mi
}
```

to this:

```
['user1','2018-04-23 16:51:10','2018-04-23 16:50','user_one',4]
['user1','2018-04-23 16:51:10','2018-04-23 16:50','user_two',4]
['user1','2018-04-23 16:51:10','2018-04-23 16:50','city_one','bs']
['user1','2018-04-23 16:51:10','2018-04-23 16:50','city_two','mi']
```

This is my code

```
let tempArr = [];

for(let key in test){

  tempArr = [];

  if(key.indexOf("user_") !== -1 || key.indexOf("city_") !== -1){

    tempArr.push(test['mainPoint']);
    tempArr.push(test['create_Date']);
    tempArr.push(test['delete_Date']);
    tempArr.push(key);
    tempArr.push(test[key]);
  }
    console.log(tempParams);
}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just not using `tempParams` to group each array

```js
const test = {
  "mainPoint": "user1",
  "create_Date": "2018-04-23 16:51:10",
  "delete_Date": "2018-04-23 16:50",
  "user_one": 4,
  "user_two": 4,
  "city_one": "bs",
  "city_two": "mi"
};
let tempParams = [];

for (let key in test) {

  tempArr = [];

  if (key.indexOf("user_") !== -1 || key.indexOf("city_") !== -1) {

    tempArr.push(test['mainPoint']);
    tempArr.push(test['create_Date']);
    tempArr.push(test['delete_Date']);
    tempArr.push(key);
    tempArr.push(test[key]);
    tempParams.push(tempArr);
  }

}
console.log(JSON.stringify(tempParams));
```

Answer (score 1):

Test with following code:

```js
{
  const test = {
    "mainPoint": "user1",
    "create_Date": "2018-04-23 16:51:10",
    "delete_Date": "2018-04-23 16:50",
    "user_one": 4,
    "user_two": 4,
    "city_one": "bs",
    "city_two": "mi"
  };
  
  let static = [], dynamic = [], final = [];
  for ( const [ key, value ] of Object.entries( test ) ) {
    if ( !key.match( /user_|city_/gi ) ) static.push( value );
    else dynamic.push( [ key, value ] );
  }
  
  for ( const item of dynamic ) {
    final.push( [ ...static, ...item ] );
  }
  
  console.log( final );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please find the working code below. In your code, you have not added tempArr into tempArrs. 

Erros in code:
    1. "city_one": and "city_two":  values are not double quotes.
    2. remove the const from test declaration
    3. remove the let from array declaration
    4. console.log should be outside.
```

```js
 test = {
    "mainPoint": "user1",
    "create_Date": "2018-04-23 16:51:10",
    "delete_Date": "2018-04-23 16:50",
    "user_one": 4,
    "user_two": 4,
    "city_one": "bs",
    "city_two": "mi"
}

tempArr = [];
tempArrs = [];

for(let key in test){

  tempArr = [];

  if(key.indexOf("user_") !== -1 || key.indexOf("city_") !== -1){
    tempArr.push(test['mainPoint']);
    tempArr.push(test['create_Date']);
    tempArr.push(test['delete_Date']);
    tempArr.push(key);
    tempArr.push(test[key]);
 tempArrs.push(tempArr);
  }
}
console.log(tempArrs);
```